# Call function of integer[] with single integer

Tags: postgresql

I have the floowing function signature in PostgreSQL:

```
func1(plist integer[])
```

i want to send this function an `intager` variable.
basicly make a call:

`select * from func1(var_integer)`

How can I do that? 
It expect `integer[]` not `integer`. Is there some sort of conversion?

**Edit:**

when I do:
`select * from func1(var_integer::integer[])`

I get:

> cannot cast type integer to integer[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from func1(array_agg(var_integer))
```

The function `array_agg(expression)` returns array of the argument type.
Thus if `var_integer` is of type `integer` the result type of `array_agg(var_integer)` is  `integer[]`

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `array_agg` here, and it won't work in more complex contexts.

Use the array constructor syntax.

```
select * from func1(ARRAY[var_integer])
```